# Pricing: AWS Dynamo db vs AWS Cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cloudwatch

Does Cloudwatch cost more than Dynamodb for storage or my understanding is wrong?

From the pricing pages:

https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/pricing/ - From this, in the logs section of us-east-1, it looks like it is costing 0.50$/GB

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/dynamodb-price-reduction-and-new-reserved-capacity-model/ - From this, it looks like it is costing 0.250$/GB.

So, here it looks like cloudwatch for logs cost more than dynamodb for actual data? Am I understanding something wrong?

I always used to think that cloudwatch is cheaper since it uses S3 or something and also logs we create are normally more than the actual data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many dimensions to the pricing for each service.

The pure storage cost for **Amazon DynamoDB** is $0.25/GB/month. (There are also costs for read/write capacity.)

The **Store (Archival)** cost for **Amazon CloudWatch Logs** is $0.03/GB/month. This is similar to Amazon S3 storage costs of $0.023/GB/month for standard storage.

The $0.50/GB figure you quote for CloudWatch appears to be the **Collect (Data Ingestion)** charge, which is not for storage.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Then, what does collect means?

Comment: I assume it refers to data that is ingested. This is because CloudWatch Logs does/can do processing on data as it arrives, beyond merely storing the logs. The **Collect (Data Ingestion)** charge would be for data as it arrives and is processed.